# Inheritance in HQL with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have set of classes which inherit from a single super class:

```
   Super
     |
     +------+-------+
     Aaaa   Bbbb    Cccc
```

Each of the Aaaa,Bbbb,Cccc then should contain method findByTag. The problem is that I can't manage to define it generally. Following example defines specific findByTag for Aaaa.

```
public interface AaaaRepository extends SuperRepository<Aaaa> {
    @Query("select distinct a from Aaaa a " +
            "join a.tags t " +
            "join fetch a.locale where t = ?1")
    public List<Event> findByTag(Tag t);
}
```

Note that the Superclass is @MappedSuperclass and does not have its own table in database.

I would like to use some kind of "Super" in the query which would be replaced in each class by its name.

My second problem is that I don't know how to force @ElementCollection to be Eagerly fetched. I have to always explicitly say "join fetch" in the query. If it is not fetched, once the transaction is finished, I can't access those objects, which I did not explicitly fetched. (LazyFetch Exceptions...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), custom implementations section, what about this approach:

1. Create an interface that extends repository and has your findByTag method, without annotations.
2. Create an implementation of that class, and in the method implementation you use the JPA criteria. You also need a class field to hold the actual class for the domain object, because generics are erased at compilation time. Then you use that field to build the criteria.
3. Read the documentation to use this implementation as a base class for the repository factory, then Spring Data will build implementations for the other repositories based on this custom one.

   ```
   public interface MyRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {        
       public List<Event> findByTag(Tag t);
   }

   public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

       private Class<T> actualClass; // initialized in the constructor

       public List<Event> findByTag(Tag t) {
            // here you build the criteria using actualClass field, and execute it.
       }
   }

   public interface AaaaRepository extends MyRepository <Aaaa, Integer> {
       // other methods...
   }
   ```

Look at "Example 1.16. Custom repository factory bean" of the documentation to create the factory bean.

When Spring instantiates the implementation of AaaaRepository, it will use MyRepositoryImpl as base class.

Will this work for you?

Comment: Well the beauty of a single annotation is lost, but I agree that there is probably no other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing it this way, I would create a data access object that resembles the pseudo java code below:

```
class DAO<T> {
     private Class<T> clazz;
     DAO( Class<T> class) { this.clazz = t; }
     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager em;

     public List<T> findByTag(Tag t ) {
        Query q = em.createQuery( "select from " + clazz.getSimpleName + "....";
        ...
        return q.getResultList();
     }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I am rather interested in achieving this with Spring data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was so unhappy about the behaviour and inflexibility of the Spring Data JPA, so that I wrote myself a small tool for building the queries in a simple way. An example of using is here:

https://github.com/knyttl/Maite/wiki/Maite-Persistence

There are two children classes and the parent class which define the functionality. But the trick is in a fluent interface of building the query.

It is just in the beggining, but it already works so that I have no duplicity and correct inheritance.

Small example of the parent class - check the link above for detail:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

protected abstract String getName();

protected Clause select() {
    return em
            .select("DISTINCT i")
            .from(this.getName(), "i")
            .joinFetch("i.locale lf")
}

public List<T> findByTag(Tag tag) {
    return (T) this.select()
            .join("i.tags t")
            .where("t = ?", tag)
            .fetchAll();
}
```